# How can I Find the size of each of the following sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I got this question for homework and can't solve it please help

Find the size of the following sets

```
1.{x|x∈Z and x^2=8}.

2.P(A), where A=P({1,2}).

3.{1,10,100,1000,…}.

4.S×T, where S={a,b,c} and T={1,2,3,4,5}.

5.{x|x∈Z and x^2<8}.
```

Comment: What does the "fallen T" mean?

Comment: What you mean by fallen T?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Solve the equation for x.
2. Calculate P(A) and count the sets.
3. That set = { 10$^n$ : n nonnegative integer }.
4. Prove |A×B| = |A|×|B|.
5. One by one find the integers with square < 2.
   How far will you have to look?

Comment: Thank you very much this help me a lot note its <8 not <2